CASL - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')
I'm implementing CASL React in a context provider. I keep getting the error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')
I define the abilities, but kepp gettingundefined in my context.
Am I defining the values correctly and should I be adding something to the context or use a different way? I can't understand wh it is undefined.
Here is my useAbility context:
export const AbilityContext = React.createContext<AnyAbility>({} as AnyAbility);
export const Can = createContextualCan(AbilityContext.Consumer)

export const defineAbilities = (): any => {

  const { can, cannot, build } = new AbilityBuilder(createMongoAbility);

  can('read', 'All');
  cannot('delete', 'Extension');
  console.log("Abilities Defined");

  const ability = build();
  return ability
};

interface IAbilityProviderProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}
export const AbilityProvider: React.FC<IAbilityProviderProps> = ({ children }) => {

  const { ability } = defineAbilities();
  return (
    <AbilityContext.Provider value={ability} >
      {children}
    </AbilityContext.Provider>
  )
};

export default function useAbilitiesActions() {
  function setAbilities() {
    defineAbilities();
  };

  return { setAbilities }
}

Here I have a button that should render the button if the user has permissions:
const ability = React.useContext(AbilityContext);
console.log(ability.can('eat', 'Meat'));

return (
  <>
    {
      data
      && (
        <div className={buttonCellClass}>
          <Can
            I="eat"
            an="meat"
            passThrough
            ability={ability}
          >
            <IconButton
              iconProps={deleteIcon}
              ariaLabel="Delete"
              text="Delete"
              onClick={() => {
                props.onDelete(data);
              }}
              //typeof props.disabled === 'function' ? props.disabled(data) : 
              disabled={false} //{ability.can('delete', 'Extension')}
            />
          </Can>
        </div>
      )
    }
  </>
);

In my App.tsx I pass AbilityProvider to the app like this:
            <AbilityProvider>
              <EventProvider>
                <Routes>
                  <Route path="/" element={<AssetList />} />
                  <Route path="/reconciler" element={<Reconciler />} />
                  {navigationHelper.map(({ id, url, page: Page }) => (
                    <Route
                      key={id}
                      path={`/${url}`}
                      element={(Page && <Page />) || null}
                    />
                  ))}
                </Routes>
              </EventProvider>
            </AbilityProvider>


There are 2 examples https://github.com/stalniy/casl-examples you can take a look. My guess is that at the moment of rendering your ability is undefined

I was trying to create ability again wtih another instance. It was null. I gave my answer below.

It means that Can received ‘ability’ as an undefined.

I was trying to create another instance unknowingly of ability. I ended up exporting ability whcih is created inside a CASL context.
Here:
import { defineAbility } from '@casl/ability';

const ability = defineAbility((can, cannot) => {
  can('manage', 'all');
  cannot('delete', 'Covenant');
  can('read', 'All');
  can('delete', 'Extension');
});

ability.can('read', 'All'); // true
ability.can('delete', 'Extension'); // false

export default ability

And then inside Can.tsx:
import { createContext } from 'react';
import { createContextualCan } from '@casl/react';
import { AnyAbility } from '@casl/ability';

export const AbilityContext = createContext<AnyAbility>({} as AnyAbility);
export const Can = createContextualCan(AbilityContext.Consumer)

